# Retrieve data based date mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have created an app with 2 models where the match refer to a specific league. From this I wan't to make a query to get all leagues which has upcoming matches. How can I do this or should I change the structure of my models? I've tried to make a query however this returns all upcoming matches instead of leagues with upcoming matches

**Models**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var leagueSchema = new Schema({
    _id: Number,
    name: String,
    league: Number
});

var matchSchema = new Schema({
    _id: Number,
    league: { type: Number, ref: 'league' },
    date: Date,
    homeName: String,
    awayName: String
});

var League  = mongoose.model('leagues', leagueSchema);
var Match = mongoose.model('matches', matchSchema);
```

**Saving data**

```
var queryData = {'_id': matchId, 'league': leagueId, 'date': date, 'homeName': homeTeam, 'awayName': awayTeam};

Match.findOneAndUpdate({'_id': matchId}, queryData, {upsert: true}, function(err, doc){
    if(err){
        console.log("Something wrong when updating data!");
    }
});
```

**Query**

```
var oneWeekAgo = new Date();
oneWeekAgo.setDate(oneWeekAgo.getDate() - 7);

Match
    .find({ "date": { "$gte": oneWeekAgo } })
    .populate('league')
    .exec(function (err, matches) {
        if (err) return handleError(err);
        console.log(matches);     
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change your models. If I were you, I would merge the two models so you will get something like this:

```
var leagueSchema = new Schema({
    _id: Number,
    name: String,
    league: Number,
    matches: [{
        date: Date,
        homeName: String,
        awayName: String
    }]
});
```

Instead of having two models, add you matches to your league schema directly. You can do this very easily when you update your document by using the [$push](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/update/push/) or [$addToSet](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/update/addToSet/) property.

If you want to add the object no matter what, use `$push`. If you want to add the item if it does not exist, use `$addToSet`. You query with only unique items will look like this:

```
var objectToPush = {
    homeName: 'Test',
    date: ISODate('2015-12-01')
};
League.update({league: 1}, {$addToSet: {matches: objectToPush}})
    .exec(function(err, update) {
        // Do something
    });
```

If you want to query for the leagues, you will need this query:

```
League.find({matches: {$elemMatch: {date: {$gte: oneWeekAgo}}}})
    .exec(function (err, matches) {
        if (err) return handleError(err);
        console.log(matches);
    });
```

This also returns matches inside your array which do not match your filter query. If you only want matches who exactly match your criteria, you will need this query:

```
League.aggregate([{
        $unwind: '$matches'
    }, {
        $match: {
            'matches.date': {
                $gte: ISODate('2015-11-01')
            }
        }
    }]);
```

The above query `$unwinds` all your array objects and then matches all items seperatly.

Comment: Okay but how would i then add matches to a specific league?

Comment: @PeterPik I have added an example in the middle of the question.

Comment: Some of the same matches might be pushed to the same league, where would i put the `upsert: true` in this case?

Comment: @PeterPik You can add `upsert` as third parameter but this creates a league without a name. So I would suggest checking if the league exists (and creating it one if it does not exists) before push a new match.

Comment: i mean the same match might be pushed several times, how do i check that it dosent?

Comment: @PeterPik Oh I see, you can use `$addToSet`. I have updated my answer.

Comment: how does the addToSet method work? i mean for instance if i have a match where the date is updated will it then create a new match or overwrite the old? or is it possible to add a id to each match which is the primary key

Comment: I do not know to be honest.

Answer (score 0):

You can use distinct to get all leagues refs, then do whatever you want with 
them :

```
 Match.find({"date":{ "$gte": oneWeekAgo }}).distinct('league', function (err, leaguesRef) {
            //      
        });
```

Or

```
Match.distinct('league', {"date":{ "$gte": oneWeekAgo }}, function (err, leaguesRef) {
        //      
    });
```

Comment: This retrieve the leagueIds, how can i add the name to the the output?

Comment: You can't in a simple query, you then need to do a query on leagues using $in and your list.
Anyway I think you should rethink your design as ThomasBormans suggested.